Selection List In ScreenFlow
When I add a Selection List item into ScreenFlow, I didn't make a selection on the screen, and then I clicked to the next screen, It showed Please select one option. error message, but I didn't set it as a required item.
I guess it's due to the Winter '25 update.
Does anyone have a way to solve this problem?

The problem has been solved. It was caused by the Winter '25 update. It is now displayed normally!
